# Poor mouse update rate on Windows RDP Client

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mac-osx, rdp

I'm using a terminal server for inking on documents in EMR (eCW).

When connecting to the same terminal server (2008 R2) the Windows RDP clients have a very slow mouse move update rate. The Mac RDP Client updates much faster and the result is drawings are smooth.

Here is an example of drawing a circle over RDP in MS Paint.

[image: Drawing a circle in MS paint over RDP]

The Mac Client is "Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 8.0.16" on OSX

The Windows Client is "Remote Desktop Connection 6.3.9600" on Windows 8.1

Comment: Is UDP open as well, or just TCP 3389?

Comment: Windows Firewall is disabled on the domain network. The clients and the server are on wired Ethernet connections.

Comment: Check the windows remote desktop client settings, experience tab, connection speed setting

Comment: It is set to "LAN" for the performance. I've also tried setting it to the modem setting. The Mac client doesn't have these options for performance and it set to the default settings.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @EdHaber?

Comment: Has anyone figure this one out? I verified that the problem is indeed the mouse polling rate by running AnyDesk as the mouse "driver" in my RDP session, and watching amazing frame rates appear in my RDP window. So the RDP client is easily able to update the screen at very high FPS, but the mouse events are just abysmally slow. Can anyone figure out a fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Butter smooth mouse updates:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client]
"Min Send Interval"=dword:00000001
"Keep Alive Interval"=dword:00000001
"BitmapCacheSize"=dword:0000ffff
"Order Draw Threshold"=dword:00000001
```